# In general $d \phi (X)$ is not defined $X$ being a vector field

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $\phi:M\to N$ be a smooth map between manifolds and $X$ a vector field on $M$. Moreover, suppose that $d\phi$ is injective at every point. I want to show that in general $d\phi (X)$ is not defined as a vector field on $N$. (Vector fields are not assumed to be smooth).

Consider the map $e: \mathbb R \to S^1$ defined by $e(t)=(cos(t),sin(t))$. $X$ is the identity map on $\mathbb R$. My calculations showed that this is such a counterexample. Is this correct?

( $de_t(a)= (-a\sin(t),a\cos(t))$ implying $de$ being injective, and $e(0)=e(2\pi)$ with $de(0)$ not equal to $de(2\pi)$.)

Comment: What vector field do you take on $\mathbb{R}$? $x\mapsto x$ ?

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to add it, I also upvoted your comment :D @AdamChalumeau

Comment: Alternatively, just choose $\phi$ not surjective.

Comment: Then $d\phi$ may not be injective. @Travis

Comment: just a small typo : $de_0$ and $de_{2\pi}$. No?

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh no, I need to work on the argument here

Comment: I mean $e(0)=e(2\pi)$ but $de(X(0))\neq de(X(2\pi))$. @ArvinRasoulzadeh

Comment: There is no must, except for the must that $d\phi$ is injective. There are non-surjections with injective differentials. @Travis

Comment: The vector field you obtain is $Y : (\cos (t), \sin(t)) \longmapsto (-t\sin(t) ,t\cos(t)\ ) $.But then $-t\sin(t) $ and $t\cos(t) $  are not $C^{\infty}$ smooth over all points of your circle. No ?

Comment: @User12239 I misread your reply. Like you say, there are nonsurjective maps $\phi$ with $d\phi$ injective. My original comment is exactly that any such map is also an example of a map $\phi : M \to N$ for which pushing forward (in fact any vector field) by $d\phi$ does not define a vector field on $N$. After all, it cannot determine a vector at any point of $N$ not in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: But a vector field is not necessarily defined in all of the space. Then your solution won’t give a solution. Am I right? @Travis

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "your solution won't give a solution". Either way "a vector field is not defined in all of the space" is exactly the point: The map $d \phi$ and vector field $X$ does not define a vector at any point in $N$ not in the image of $\phi$ and hence cannot define a vector field on $N$.

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh sorry, the vector fields are not assumed to be smooth. I’ll edit my question

Comment: If $f_i$ are functions $N\to \Bbb{R}$ and $n_i$ are coordinates (functions too) and $\phi : M \to N$ is differentiable then
$\sum_i f_i(n)dn_i$ is a vector field on $N$ and $\sum_i f_i(\phi(m)) d\phi(m)_i$ is a vector field on $M$. The opposite works if $\phi$ is a local homeomorphism so locally you can do the same with $\phi^{-1} : N \to M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This choice indeed gives a counterexample, but the explanation would benefit from some polishing, especially since the chosen vector field $X \in \Gamma(T \Bbb R)$, $X_s := t \partial_s$, as well as the use of the canonical isomorphisms $T_s \Bbb R \cong \Bbb R$, that might lead to confusion. (The vector field $X$ is sometimes called the *Euler vector field*.)

The chosen map is $$e : \Bbb R \to S^1 \subset \Bbb R^2, \qquad e : t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t),$$ and so $$de_s(a \partial_t\vert_s) = (-a \sin s, a \cos s),$$ where we implicitly use the canonical identification $T_{e(s)} \Bbb R^2 \cong \Bbb R^2$. Like you say, $e(0) = e(2 \pi)$, but
$$de_0 (X_0) = de_0 (0 \partial_t\vert_0) = (0, 0) \in T_{(1, 0)} S^1$$ but
$$de_{2 \pi} (X_{2 \pi}) = de_{2 \pi} (2 \pi \partial_t \vert_{2 \pi}) = (0, 2 \pi) \in T_{(1, 0)} S^1 .$$
Thus $e$ and $X$ do not determine a preferred vector in $T_{(1, 0)} S^1$ and hence do not determine a preferred vector field on $S^1$.

---

As discussed in the comments, another way to show that pushing forward the vectors in a vector field $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ by a map $F : M \to N$ does not determine a vector field on $N$ is to consider any vector field $X$ and any nonsurjective map $F$. If $q \in N$ is not in the image of $F(M)$, the set $\{dF_p(X_p) : p \in M\}$  contains no vector in $T_q N$ and hence $F$ and $X$ do not specify a vector field on $N$.

Comment: Thanks, this is a complete illustration of the question.

Comment: However, $F$ being non-surjective would a little make the question trivial so it would have been better if I had asked the map to be surjective.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful!